# How to bind policies to the default REST endpoints in Sails.js?

Tags: javascript, rest, sails.js

So,
I have a User model and a UserController.js file but with no functions in it.
So the default REST endpoints are working for User model..

Now I am able to put a policy on the REST POST request on /user by putting the undergiven in my /config/policies.js file:

UserController: {
    "create" : 'authenticated',
    }

where 'authenticated' is the policy that I defined.
So it seems that "create" is mapped to default REST "post /user" ...

Now my question is how do I put a policy for "get /user/:id" ...  ?
Is there a verb (like create for POST on /user) for /user/:id?

I hope I am clear enough..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sails, policies were designed to be applied to controllers and not individual routes.  Thankfully, the framework is flexible enough that it's not too difficult to find workarounds for things like this.

There are a few ways to do this. Either way, you will need to catch the http request inside of the routes configuration file in `config/routes.js`.

If you only need to apply one policy to the route/method, the easiest thing to do is put it directly inside of the routes config file. For example.

```
module.exports.routes = {
'/': {
    view: 'homepage'
},
'get /user': function(req,res,next){
    console.log('I made a get request!! ')
},
'post /user': function(req,res,next){
    console.log('I made a post request!! ')
}
```

};

If you want to apply more than one policy to the route/method or you prefer keeping your policies in the policies folder, try something like below.

```
var policyOne = require('../api/policies/policyOne');
var policyTwo = require('../api/policies/policyTwo');

module.exports.routes = {
    '/': {
        view: 'homepage'
    },
    'get /user': [policyOne,policyTwo]
};
```

Comment: The latter solution doesn't work for me. The first works fine.

Answer (score 6):

According to this http://beta.sailsjs.org/#!documentation/reference/Blueprints/Blueprints.html these are the default actions available in blueprints:

-find
-findOne
-create
-update
-destroy
-populate
-add
-remove

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to bind my policies correctly without having to write a bunch of controller/router code to recreate what already existed.

Comment: The answer is not relevant to the question!

Comment: While this was more than 3 years ago, the idea was to use the verbs listed in my answer above to reference the blueprint actions in the policies configuration. Haven't played with Sails.js for quite some time now, it'll be interesting to see how it evolved now, hence i'm not sure if anything mentioned here still applies though.